# Starting activity results java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: android, exception, null

I have an activity in manifest:

```
<activity android:name="RingdroidSelectActivity"
          android:label="@string/main_activity_label">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

When using the following code to open it:

```
startActivity (new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.ringdroid.RingdroidSelectActivity.class));
```

I get:

```
06-03 09:49:32.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11360): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-03 09:49:32.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11360): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ringdroid/com.ringdroid.RingdroidSelectActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-03 09:49:32.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11360):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
06-03 09:49:32.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11360):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-03 09:49:32.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11360):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-03 09:49:32.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11360):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-03 09:49:32.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11360):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-03 09:49:32.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11360):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-03 09:49:32.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11360):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-03 09:49:32.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11360):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 09:49:32.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11360):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-03 09:49:32.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11360):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-03 09:49:32.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11360):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-03 09:49:32.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11360):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-03 09:49:32.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11360): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-03 09:49:32.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11360):     at com.ringdroid.RingdroidSelectActivity.onCreate(RingdroidSelectActivity.java:108)
06-03 09:49:32.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11360):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-03 09:49:32.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11360):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-03 09:49:32.744: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11360):     ... 11 more
```

Any idea?

Comment: The problem seems to be in your activity's code, not in the launch itself. Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.ringdroid.RingdroidSelectActivity.onCreate(RingdroidSelectActivity.java:108) . Post `RingdroidSelectActivity.java`

Comment: What's on RingdroidSelectActivity.java:108?

Comment: It has the code that makes the error:
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        mWasGetContentIntent = intent.getAction().equals(
                Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

Comment: Ah, to reiterate @dmon's point: your error is on line 108 of `RingdroidSelectActivity.java`. Fix whatever is null on that line and you should be all set. The error contains all the information you need to fix this.

Comment: I included what is on line 108:
Intent intent = getIntent(); mWasGetContentIntent = intent.getAction().equals( Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
Don't know what's the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have intent.getAction()== null obviously.

Fix your line of code to:

```
mWasGetContentIntent = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT.equals(intent.getAction());
```

Comment: You dont have to specify an action if you are specifying the class of the activity to launch

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this code:

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); 
mWasGetContentIntent = intent.getAction().equals( Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
```

It's best practice (and common sense) when using the `.equals()` to put what you *know* not to be null on the left side, so you avoid these `NullPointerException`s. So rewrite it to be:

```
mWasGetContentIntent =  Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT.equals(intent.getAction());
```